# JSON: Check URL before loading it

Tags: objective-c, json

Is there a way to check an URL before loading it? Reason why is because I have a URL that is changed dynamically and after multiple changes, the URL returns null and sometimes error on JSON.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: If you provide more information, we might be able to help you. What's the URL look like when it works? What's the URL look like when it doesn't? What web service are you going to?

Comment: The URL changes depending on the user device date and you can skip between dates as well, but then, I can go up to certain dates. I can go from today up to 15 days for example but the 16th date, is null because it hasn't been populated yet on the database.

Comment: So you mean you need some logic in the app to check validity? Because the only way to check if the URL returns data or an error is to try loading it...

Comment: Well, if thats what it takes of course yes.

Comment: Are you using a UIWebView?